# When should I use templates and when overloaded functions?

Tags: c++, oop, templates, programming-languages

I am confused. I never seem to decide what to use,  a template or an overloaded function. Overloads need more coding. So in what cases is it preferred to use templates and in what overloaded functions?

For example, i recently had to take this decision while making a small GBA game. There were two types **u16** and **int** and i decided to use overloaded functions.

```
inline void Point::Move(int x, int y) {_ix += x; _iy += y; }
inline void Point::Move(u16 x, u16 y) {_ix += (int) x; _iy += (int) y; }
```

should I have used a template instead? And in what cases should I use an overloaded function?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Basic Rule should be:

Use **Templates** when you want to perform **same functionality/Operations** on **different data types**.

Use **overloaded functions** when you want to perform **different functionality/Operations** on **different/same data types**

Also, A good measure of when you really need a overloaded function over template is when you are making too many explicit specializations for a templated version of function.

In your example if you performing same operations in both the versions of the functions, You should use templates, else you should use Overloaded function.

Comment: **Can I haz moar BOLD?** (+1)

Comment: @Als He meant that you have **A LOT OF BOLD TEXT**

Answer (score 3):

As far as I can see a template solution would result in the same compiled object but no repetition in the source. A clear win for templates.

I don't understand the point about templates needing more memory. That sounds like a misthink.

Comment: That's the kind of muddled-up false info i get by reading forums . "Templates need more memory!!!" and "Templates are Slow!!!" and a hundred and one things against templates and vice versa. So sorry about that

Comment: I think use of templates can make life hard for the compiler. Perhaps that's where the memory/slow vibes come from

Comment: templates are not slow, since at compile time they are translated into specific types (compile time might be slower when using templates). about memory: if you create 3 concrete functions from your template, then you need 3*function copies. if you overload 3 functions, you also have 3 copies of it, so memory usage is the same. (and it can be neglected anyway in most of the cases)

Answer (score 1):

Usually you would overload a function when you know the types that you are going to use.

Usually you will overload a function when there's an actual logical difference (different code) between the types you're using.
And you can do that because you know the actual types and their traits.

The power of templates is that you can write the function it once, and then use the method for any type you want.
But the template should be general enough to fit any type given to it.